# Generator yield value difference

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-harmony, yield-keyword

Let's we say that we have following generator function:

```
var gen1 = function * (){
  yield 1;
};
```

And we have two more generators which yields above generator:

```
var gen2 = function * () {
    yield gen1;
};

var gen3 = function * () {
    yield *gen1;
};
```

Does someone known what is difference between `yield gen1`  `yield *gen1`.
What does `*` do to generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

QUOTE:

The `yield*` operator delegates to another generator. This provides a convenient mechanism for composing generators.

The expression `yield* <<expr>>` is equivalent to:

```
let (g = <<expr>>) {
    let received = void 0, send = true, result = void 0;
    try {
        while (true) {
            let next = send ? g.send(received) : g.throw(received);
            try {
                received = yield next;
                send = true;
            } catch (e) {
                received = e;
                send = false;
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        if (!isStopIteration(e))
            throw e;
        result = e.value;
    } finally {
        try { g.close(); } catch (ignored) { }
    }
    result
}
```

This is similar to a `for-in` loop over the generator, except that it propagates exceptions thrown via the outer generator’s `throw` method into the delegated generator.

---

Source:
http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:generators#delegating_yield

---

I haven't taken much time to fully understand it, but `yield* gen;` seems similar to `yield gen();` Correct me if I'm wrong (though I fully suspect there will be some corner cases, such as the context of any exceptions.)

Answer (score 2):

The effect of your code is like this:

```
for (let x of gen1()) console.log(x)  // "1"
for (let x of gen2()) console.log(x)  // "function* gen1() { yield 1; }"
for (let x of gen3()) console.log(x)  // throws TypeError
```

What you probably meant was:

```
var gen2 = function* () {
  yield gen1();
};

var gen3 = function* () {
  yield* gen1();
};
```

In that case you get:

```
for (let x of gen2()) console.log(x)  // "[object Object]"
for (let x of gen3()) console.log(x)  // "1"
```

That is, a plain `yield` just returns whatever the operand expression evaluates to (in the case of `gen2`, an unused iterator object). A `yield*` on the other hand *delegates* to another iterator. It will yield whatever that iterator yields, until it is exhausted. More concretely:

```
function* g() { yield 1; yield 2; yield 3 }
function* h() { yield 4; yield* g(); yield 5 }
function* i() { yield 6; yield* h(); yield 7 }

for (let x of i()) console.log(x)  // 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7
```

Comment: I think the definition of `* i()` should be `{ yield 6; yield* h(); yield 7 }`